# How to create a Javascript Hash Table / Associate Array Prototype

Tags: javascript, prototype, associative-array

With a associative array such as:

```
var m = {};
m['a'] = {id:1, foo:'bar'};
m['b'] = {id:2, foo:'bar'};
```

Is it possible to create a prototype such as:

```
Array.prototype.hello = function() { console.log('hello'); }
m.hello();
```

This fails because m is an object, so I tired:

```
Object.prototype.hello = function() { console.log('hello'); }
```

and this is problematic too.

Is is possible to create a prototype which can operate on this data structure?

---

Update:
I think I need some sleep :)

When I create and use the `Object.prototype.hello = function() { console.log('hello'); }` by itself it works fine.

When I add the prototype and include a 3rd party JS Framework, it makes the framework stop working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign custom properties to any object, and that means you can do so on an object with a different immediate underlying prototype than `Object.prototype`. So you could do this, for instance:

```
function MyMap() {
}
MyMap.prototype.hello = function() {
    console.log('hello');
};
var m = new MyMap();
m['a'] = {id:1, foo:'bar'};
m['b'] = {id:2, foo:'bar'};
m.hello();
```

**Note**, though, that if you stored a `hello` entry:

```
m['hello'] = {id:3, foo:'bar'};
```

...it would hide the `hello` that your object gets from the prototype.

Also note that your `m` will have the properties not only from `MyMap.prototype`, but also from `Object.prototype` (like `{}` does), like `toString` and `valueOf` and `hasOwnProperty`. If you want to **not** have `Object`properties, you can do that, too:

```
function MyMap() {
}
MyMap.prototype = Object.create(null);
MyMap.prototype.hello = function() {
    console.log('hello');
};
```

Also note that constructor functions (`MyMap`, above) are only one way to create objects with an underlying prototype. You can just use `Object.create` directly:

```
var mapPrototype = {
    hello: function() {
        console.log('hello');
    }
};
var m = Object.create(mapPrototype);
```

Comment: I am going to try your last suggestion.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: @BrianMcGinity: No worries. Note that it has the same conflict issue that all the others do. :-) The only way around the conflicts problem would be to store the entries on a different object, like ES6's `map` conceptually does.

Answer (score 2):

Why not create your own object constructor so that you can extend its prototype without issues?

```
function O(o) {
    for (var p in o) {
        this[p] = o[p];
    }
}

O.prototype.hello = function() { console.log('hello') }
```

Then use the constructor with your object literals.

```
var m = new O({})
m['a'] = {id:1, foo:'bar'}
m['b'] = {id:2, foo:'bar'}
```

There are tricks that'll let you drop the `new` if you wish.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `Object.create` to create an array-like prototype for your structure.

```
var proto = Object.create(Array.prototype);
proto.hello = function() { console.log('hello'); }
```

Then use it like

```
var stack = Object.create(proto);
stack.hello();
stack.push('example');
```

Answer (score 0):

Assigning to Object.prototype should work just fine. When running in node:

```
> Object.prototype.foo = function() { console.log("foo!"); }
[Function]
> var m = {};
undefined
> m.foo();
foo!
undefined
```

Whether it is a good idea is a whole other discussion...